# what is the direct way to copy a joda LocalTime?

Tags: java, jodatime

I want a new instance that is a copy.  I could instantiate from integers but it seems there should be a more direct way.  I could also use some sort of approach like `copy = original.minus(zero)` but that is also indirect.

The LocalTime constructor that accepts a Java Object argument (for which I used the original LocalTime) does not work.  I guess it just does not support it.

```
        LocalTime start = new LocalTime(9, 0, 0);
        LocalTime stop = new LocalTime(17, 0, 0);

        //LocalTime time = start.minusSeconds(0);  // GOOD VERSION
        LocalTime time = new LocalTime(start);     // THE BAD VERSION

        assert time == start: "does not work";

        // EXTRANEOUS STUFF TO JUSTIFY COPYING AN IMMUTABLE, FOLLOWS...
        while (time.compareTo(stop) <= 0)
        {
            //method(time, new LocalTime(9, 0, 0), stop); // MESSY
            method(time, start, stop);                    // NICER
            time = time.plusMinutes(1);
        }
```

I also tried `copy = new LocalTime(original.getLocalMillis())` but I do not have access to `getLocalMillis` as it is protected.

Comment: The reason your assert fails is because the `==` compares object references, not the values within them. Your `start` and `end` references point to different objects (they were both `new`'d separately) that happen to have the same values. You should instead use the `.equals()` method instead. Have a read of this: http://leepoint.net/notes-java/data/expressions/22compareobjects.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

LocalTime is immutable, so there is no point holding on to 2 instances with the same value.  They can be shared (even across threads).  The mutation methods, e.g. plus/minus will return a new value, so you can create your copy "on demand" when you need the modified value.

```
LocalTime start = new LocalTime(9, 0, 0);
LocalTime stop = new LocalTime(17, 0, 0);
LocalTime time = start;     // Just use the reference

while (time.compareTo(stop) <= 0)
{
    method(time, start, stop);
    time = time.plusMinutes(1);
}
```

Comment: I won't hold onto 2 identical instances because I will increment the copy in a loop.  I still want the original because "original" is nicer to read than "new LocalTime(a, b, c)"

Comment: To be more accurate, since the object is immutable there will not be any actual incrementing, but the previous-to-being "incremented" object will get garbage collected and I still have a ref to an original.

Comment: I still don't understand the reason for the copy.  Just hang on to the original reference.  Creating a copy so that the original can be GC'd provides no benefit as you are allocating just as many objects as you are allowing to be GC'd.  It might be useful to post a simplified version of your loop.

Answer (score 0):

This works just fine for me:

```
LocalTime t1 = new LocalTime();
try {
   // Sleep for a bit just to make sure the current system time moves on
   Thread.sleep(5000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) { }
LocalTime t2 = new LocalTime(t1);
assertEquals(t1, t2);
```

Note the second-to-last line - I think that's what you're looking for. `t2` gets the same time in milliseconds since the epoch as `t1`.

So what do you mean exactly when you say that the copy constructor (which I've used OK above) "does not work"?

Comment: I will post my code to show it did not work.  Are you sure you have assert turned on in your IDE?

Comment: I don't know why this was down voted.  It's pretty shocking to me that Eclipse has assert turned off by default.

Comment: Sigh, I wish downvoters would explain themselves. I ran that code before posting it and it works, and it answers the OP's questions. @broiyan - I was using `assertEquals()` from TestNG, if it helps.

Comment: See my comment on your original post - your assert() was coded incorrectly.